# The fractional seconds precision issue with PowerBuilder and SQL server 2016

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder

I have a simple stored procedure to return a datetime. e.g:

```
create procedure sp_get_date (@db_date datetime output)as begin      select @db_date ='2017-04-26 13:20:32.313' end
```

And using SQLNCLI11 native client to work with the datatbase inside the PowerBuilder application.

```
DECLARE get_date_proc PROCEDURE for dbo.sp_get_date @db_date = :dt_today output using sqlca;
EXECUTE get_date_proc;
FETCH get_date_proc INTO :dt_today;
t_now = time(dt_today)
```

The expected result for t_now is "13:20:32.**313000**"

When use SQL sever 2014, the t_now value is correct with 13:20:32.**313000**

But with SQL server 2016, the value is  13:20:**3133333**

Is that the problem with native client library to work with SQL server 2016? Is the stored procudure return a datatime2 value?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3104723

Comment: see DanGuzman comment

Comment: Yup, I can change to level 120.
But still don't understand the root causes. Does above stored proceudre return DATETIME2 value instead of DATETIME in SQL server 2016?

Comment: you must be having data type mismatches and those resulted in higher precision

Comment: i am not sure about powerbuilder,but the reason is clear,some where you/application is converting from datetime to datetime2

Comment: Info: datetime (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) datetime2 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql). Try the following: `create procedure sp_get_date (@db_date datetime2 output)as begin      select @db_date ='2017-04-26 13:20:32.313' end`

Comment: All the related codes are posted above, we just declare and execute the procedure, fetch value to dt_today, and assign t_now variable. Really don't know where the conversion happened.

Comment: @Eduardo G: We cannot change all stored procedures to use Datetime2

Comment: Microsoft deprecated the native client in SQL Server 2016.  They now recommend OLE DB.  Perhaps the issue is with the older driver?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running into this sql server bug (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2805477). So it seems the best approach may be to convert the datatype of your parameter to datetime2. Alternatively, it might help to implement the procedure as a RPC in your PB app; I can't really say if that does anything since I'm still using ss 2012.